# How to define a custom slot that can be any name orstring value?

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit, amazon-echo

I am building a cricket stats alexa skill which requires the `playerName` to filter out information. I cannot use `AMAZON.US_FIRST_NAME` because of the following reasons:

- It only detects the first name and not the whole name
- There are `playerName` from around the globe, so `AMAZON.US_FIRST_NAME` isn't a good fit.

Even if I want to use `AMAZON.LITERAL` (which is not recommended by Amazon) I need to have slot values. But the slot values can be any player names, so the sample utterances will be huge.

One way to do this is to hard-code all `playerName` with slot values. But is it a best practice to do this since the slot values can be quite big in number?

Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: I will recommend you to use the AMAZON.US_FIRST_NAME only and as user tell the name of player, you can prompt user that there are multiple name with the initial and to get the information please provide last name OR club OR country name OR date of birth if remember.

Answer (score 0):

Use Custom slot https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/custom-interaction-model-reference.html#custom-slot-type-values , currently you can have 50,000 custom slot values ( which i feel are sufficient for player names ). 
e.g.

**Intent Schema**

```
{
  "intents": [
    {
      "slots": [
        {
          "name": "PLAYER_NAME",
          "type": "PLAYERS"
        }
      ],
      "intent": "GetPlayerData"
    }
  ]
}
```

Custom_Slot_Value
Type **PLAYERS**

Sachin,

Saurabh, 
....

Comment: Yes, that is the only solution as of now to hardcode player names. Depending on the data update, `playerName` can have new values and that's when it won't work.

Comment: you always can use ASK CLI interface to update it ( write cron job to read player names from database etc )  https://developer.amazon.com/docs/smapi/ask-cli-command-reference.html . Its in beat version so i'm sure amazon will provide good examples in future...

Comment: but it's not capturing normal name with First and Last name both for example "Pardep Jain" it will pick only first one or sometimes other name

Comment: @PardeepJain - please check in input log what value is printed for pardeep?

Comment: its showing "Pradeep", "Pardip", "pradeep jaan" etc, but not "Pardeep Jain". Same happened with another name which is "Danny stone" whereas skill is showing "danny", "dannys tone" "dannies" etc

Comment: connect with their support team https://developer.amazon.com/public/support/contact/contact-us